# Going back to the page before by pressing the button in the browser

Tags: html

I have two html pages.

I enter to the first page, press the button and go to the second page.
The problem is that when Im in the second page (signin.html) and I press the back button from the browser I dont go to the first page (welcome.html) I go to some other previous page. I need to be able to go back by pressing that button, how can I achive that?

**html 1 welcome.html**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
        Welcome page 
    </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div>
<div class="button">
<input name="account" type="button" value="I am a service provider" onclick="window.location.replace('/member/sign-in.html')"/>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**html 2 signin.html**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    Member sign in
    </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form id="myform" action="/my-code/signInMember.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="spEmail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="spEmail" name="spEmail" required/>       
</div>
<div>
    <label for="spPswd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="spPswd" name="spPswd" required/>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="sign up for free"  onclick="window.location.replace('/member/create-account.html')"/>
</div>
<div/>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any ideas? I was looking around and everybody say to add a button to go back (with php or javascript) but I dont want that. I want to press the browser button and then go back, no with a button in the page itself.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onclick event rather than using `"window.location.replace('/member/sign-in.html')"` use `"window.location.href='/member/sign-in.html'"` or `"window.location.href='member/sign-in.html'"` according to your path of destination html.

Comment: Do I have to add anything else in the second page? Cause is still doing the same... (thanks)

Comment: No you don't need to do anything. make sure all quotes and paths are proper.

Answer (score 1):

thanks, I changed as suggested:

```
<form>
    <input TYPE="button" VALUE="Offer this service"
    onclick="window.location.href='/member/signin.html'"> 
</form>
```

And it worked!